# Where is the free transform function for 2D animation?

Tags: 2d

There is no select tool, so I don't think there will be free transform tool. Are you sure you don't have one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean by that? People call different things on different software. You must describe exactly what you are trying to achieve or note what past software you have used.

If you are talking about moving a flat plane on only 2 axes you can go to the object tab and there will be a little lock icon next to each digit where you can lock the transform of one so that that it now only moves around the axis that you have. Then press "G" to move something without using the gizmo.

If you want to manipulate the shapes of 2d images then you would have to create a plane and apply that image is an image texture. You can do this by simply adding a material then texture and selecting "Image" if it's not already there by default. Then it will prompt you to load in your image. If it's already there you can simply select it from the drop-down menu. Then you can have two screens open. One for the 3D viewport and the other for the UV editor. You can unwrap it but it would already be unwrapped since it's just a plane. Then when you are in edit mode you should be able to select the UV island and deform it as you wish.

Comment: Free transform is a concept used to freely transform 2d pictures in animate cc, photoshop, and clipstudio. I have confirmed that I can use it by pressing the g key with the protocol edit mode on in the blender.

Comment: Ah yes, as I answered it in the last paragraph. Could you please mark my answer as the correct one so others can find the answer?